# I have a map that's a vector image. Whats the best way of showing this in android?

Tags: android

I want to add a vector that's a map. I want to show this to the user, but I'm unsure of the best way to do this.

The only requirements I have are:
Show a vector
Start "zoomed" in (start at a specific point of the the map)
Work on 4.0 and up

Comment: "I have a map that's a vector image. Whats the best way of showing this in android?" -- that depends on what the vector image file format is.

Comment: I don't want to specify one. I want to keep it a vector (for max clarity when zooming in), but I don't have a specific file type to go with.

Comment: "I don't want to specify one" -- then I have no idea what you think a "vector image" is. [Here is a Wikipedia list of vector image formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats#Vector_formats) so you know what you have to choose from. If it is from none of those, where is this "vector image" coming from?

Comment: Well, I have an Adobe Illustrator file. Which is a vector image. I can export it out to multiple file types? I currently use .SVG whenever someone asks me to design something. But I believe a pdf can handle vectors as well as some others.

Comment: Hmm... re-reading your reply. I meant "I don't want to specify one" as "I'm up for suggestion on which file type to use"

Answer (score 0):

> I'm up for suggestion on which file type to use

Ah, that is definitely not how I interpreted "I don't want to specify one".

SVG is probably the lightest-weight solution. There are [libraries that can display SVG](http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=svg) in an `ImageView` as a `Drawable`, though these will only handle a subset of SVG. `WebView` on Android 3.0+ is supposed to be able to handle SVG files, though I haven't tried it.

Many, perhaps most, Android users have a PDF viewer, so if you're willing to open up a third-party app, you can do that easily enough. There are [PDF libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=pdf) as well, though PDF is a more complex file format than is SVG, and therefore the libraries suffer.

I am not aware of any easy way to show an AI file directly, and those are the primary 2D vector formats in use today.

Comment: Okay, I will try my hand at one of those SVG libraries. Since it renders it in an ImageView... how would I get zooming functionality? I suppose I could use this: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: @EGHDK: There are [libraries that offer zoomable `ImageView` replacements](http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=zoom). BTW, [the Android Arsenal](http://android-arsenal.com/) has a pretty good search feature. :-)

Comment: Thanks. Haven't heard of Android Arsenal. With those zoomable image views... do you think I could make it start zoomed in to a specific location on the map?

Comment: @EGHDK: Only with difficulty. That will be true for any solution, though. None of these things know anything about "maps" and "locations". You'll have to somehow figure out what that position translates to in terms of pixel coordinates for the vector image as rendered at a particular size.